# How do I access a derived class value from a base class static method?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    public static T GetByID(int ID)
    {
        // Need database name here that is determined at design time in the derived class.
        var databaseName = "";
        // do some stuff involving database name that gets me object by ID here.
        return default(T);
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    private string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, how would I access the derived "DatabaseName" in the base class static GetByID method?

EDIT: After I posted this, I tried one more thing.  I played with attributes earlier, and failed, but I think my brain was mushy.  Just tried again and ran a test, and it is working.  Here is the updated sample.

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    public static T GetByID(int ID)
    {
        // Need database name here that is determined at design time in the derived class.
        var databaseName = ((DatabaseAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), true).First()).DatabaseName;
        // do some stuff involving database name that gets me object by ID here.
        return default(T);
    }
}
[Database("MyDatabase")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{

}
public class DatabaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DatabaseAttribute(string databaseName)
    {
        DatabaseName = databaseName;
    }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the database name setup into the static initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Base class to derived class is a one-way inheritance: The base class has no knowledge of the existance of a derived class, and so it can't access it.

In addition to that you will have a hard time accessing a non-static property from a static method.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already answered your own question, but some improvements....

Add a where clause to guarantee inheritance, it means any static methods can make use of inherited methods.  You might also want to add the `new()` clause if you wish to be able to create instances of the inherited class.

```
public class BaseClass<T> : where T : BaseClass<T>
{

    static readonly string databaseName;


    static BaseClass() {
      // Setup database name once per type of T by putting the initialization in
      // the static constructor

      databaseName = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute),true)
                              .OfType<DatabaseAttribute>()
                              .Select(x => x.Name)
                              .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static T GetByID(int ID)
    {
        // Database name will be in the static field databaseName, which is unique
        // to each type of T

        // do some stuff involving database name that gets me object by ID here.
        return default(T);
    }
}

[Database("MyDatabase")]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{

}

public class DatabaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DatabaseAttribute(string databaseName)
    {
        DatabaseName = databaseName;
    }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```